# How to you calculate the proportion distribution of a feature's categories based on another feature

Tags: python, pandas, distribution

I'm using the [adult dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult) from the UCI repository and I wish to calculate the proportion of income >50k or <50k for each of the different categories in the race column.

SO basically what I'm after is a proper representation of the proportion of the income based on race. which is skewed if you only take into consideration the count of each race:

```
ax = sns.countplot(x=adults_full['income'], hue=adults_full['race'], palette="pastel")
ax.set_xticklabels(['<50k', '>50k'])
ax.set_title('Income vs Race')
```

[image]

Here it shows that white ppl in the majority earn more than 50k only because there are more of them in the dataset.

In reality and proportionally "Asian pacific islander" have a comparable ratio of income >50k compared to "white" but is barely represented here and I'm not sure how to go about it (I'm a noob)

```
print(adults_full['race'].value_counts())
adults_full[['race', 'income']].value_counts()

White                 38903
Asian-Pac-Islander     1303

race                income
White               0         28696
                    1         10207
Asian-Pac-Islander  0           934
                    1           369
```

where 0 is <50k and 1 is >50k

UPDATE:

Thanks to the comment below I was able to get my result using the following:

```
pivot = pd.crosstab(adults_full.race, adults_full.income, normalize='index')
pivot.sort_values(by = 1, inplace = True)
pivot.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: `pd.crosstab(adults_full['income'], adults_full['race'], normalize='columns').plot.bar()`.

Comment: thanks @QuangHoang, how would you group and sort them by income? (each or the race having 2 columns for each of the 2 income categories and sorted by income >50k for example)

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for the pointer, write your solution as an answer and I'll mark as the answer